# How to specify customized emacs configuration file rather than "~/.emacs"?

Tags: linux, emacs, lisp, config

I just want emacs to load another file as the configuration file, and ignore the default file ("~/.emacs").

Note that I don't want to change the original "~/.emacs" file.

I've tried to change "$HOME" env variable, but it doesn't work.

(Platform is Linux.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Emacs manual, [section 48.4](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File):

> Emacs looks for your init file using the filenames ‘~/.emacs’, ‘~/.emacs.el’, or ‘~/.emacs.d/init.el’ you can choose to use any one of these three names […].

If you really want to use another file, you should consider patching Emacs and making a custom build.  It looks like [lisp/startup.el:1009](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/startup.el#n1009) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 8):

```
emacs --no-init-file --load=some-other-config.el
```

Or with short options:

```
emacs -q -l some-other-config.el
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the only option is to use `-u` to indicate another user's init file.

Answer (score 1):

As @Benjamin quoted, there are three filenames you can choose. As normally, we choose `~/.emacs.d/init.el` to be loaded. That's because, we can simply add more configuration files in this directory and add them all under version control(Git). Be sure `~/.emacs` and `~/.emacs.el` removed before u choose to use the `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.